# C# Actions/Classes

Tags: c#, class, object, action

[image: Picture of Program Design]

I have to design a program that operates like this.  I've got done the basic code for the robot movement, however the directions require that I use an "Action" class with a display method.

Add a new class called Action that will expose the following pieces of data:|

1.) ActionType
2.) Direction
3.) Distance
3.) Display()

o The Display method of the Action class should emit RobotDirection.X where X is the full name for the direction

or MoveRobot(X) where the X is the distance selected.
o Add a list of type Action to keep track of the Direction and Movement instructions entered by the user

o Add a listbox and for every item in the list of Actions, call the Display() method and add that information to the
listbox

As of right now, I have an enums class as:

```
public enum ActionType
{
    Movement,
    Direction
}
public enum RobotDirection
{
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West
}
```

And in my Actions class:

```
 public String Display(Action x)
    {
        String robotAction = null;

        if(x.ActionType == ActionType.Direction)
        {
            if(x.Direction == RobotDirection.North)
            {
                robotAction = "RobotDirection.North";
            }
            else if(x.Direction == RobotDirection.East)
            {
                robotAction = "RobotDirection.East";
            }
            else if(x.Direction == RobotDirection.South)
            {
                robotAction = "RobotDirection.South";
            }
            else if(x.Direction == RobotDirection.West)
            {
                robotAction = "RobotDirection.West";
            }

        }

        else if (x.ActionType == ActionType.Movement)
        {
            robotAction = "MoveRobot(" + Distance + ")";
        }

        return robotAction;

    }
}
```

How would I call the Display method to populate the listbox?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the question in Your post/what is the problem.

Comment: My problem is I don't understand how to properly use the Display method to populate the list box.  While I have the Display method, nothing connects it to the Listbox and I'm not sure x. stands for in this case.

Comment: @user7200174 have you seen the documentation of the [ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes I have and normally I would just hard code the buttons to add an item to the listbox, but the display method has to be used in combination with the enums to populate the listbox.

Comment: @user7200174 Okay. If I understand correctly, the Direction and Movement instructions are entered by the user. When the user adds an instruction, you need to create a new `Action` object containing the details of the instruction. This `Action` object needs to be added to a `List<Action>`. And once all instructions are entered, you need to call `Display()` from every `Action` in the `List` and add it to your `ListBox` (e.g. like `foreach(var a in myActionList) { yourListBox.Items.Add(a.Display()); }`?

Comment: Yes!  Using the enums class and creating a list of Actions (and not a List<int> or something like that)  is what is really throwing me off about this assignment.

Comment: @user7200174 Ah so perhaps it's also a matter of using a constructor the right way? Do you have a constructor for your `Action` class? It should be defined as `public Action(ActionType type, RobotDirection direction, int distance) { this.type = type; this.direction = direction; this.distance = distance; }`. Be sure to have fields for type, direction and distance in your class. You can also use `this.type` and `this.direction` in your `Display` method then, and you also don't need any arguments for your `Display` method (i.e. `Display()` instead of `Display(Action x)`).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to help make it work!  Thank you!

Comment: @user7200174 No problem, glad you've got what you're looking for! I've also created an answer now, with a little more information. You can upvote and accept it if you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `Action` class is that you need a constructor and fields, and you shouldn't need to pass an `Action` to your `Display` method as an argument.

First add some fields to your `Action` class:

```
public class Action
{
    private ActionType type;
    private RobotDirection direction;
    private int distance;
```

Next, add a constructor in your class:

```
    public Action(ActionType type, RobotDirection direction, int distance)
    { 
        this.type = type;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
```

You can call this constructor to create a new `Action` object as followed: `var action = new Action(ActionType.Direction, RobotDirection.North, 10);`

You can also use `this.type` and `this.direction` in your `Display` method, and you also don't need any arguments for your `Display` method (i.e. `Display()` instead of `Display(Action x)`).

One last thing which might be of interest to you: [Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) and [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx). You can make new classes, for example `MovementAction` and `RotateAction`, and make them implement `IAction`, which will then be an interface containing only a `Display()` method.

The `MovementAction` class will only contain the fields for `ActionType type` and `int distance`. The `RotateAction` class will only contain the fields for `ActionType type` and `RobotDirection direction`. And they will both implement the `Display()` method in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You should call this method to a string:

```
string specificAction = Display(/*any action*/)
```

And then add the string to your ListBox:

```
yourListBox.Items.Add(specificAction)
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: The question states the following: "Add a list of type Action to keep track of the Direction and Movement instructions entered by the user". Your answer does not include that, but I do agree that your solution is the right one if this `List<Action>` isn't used for anything else besides keeping track of inputted actions, because, in that case, this list is pretty useless.